# ASP.NET MVC WebAPI JsonContent return stream not JSON as expected at WebServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I am trying get data from WebAPI like this:

http://*****/Api/Customers/GetAll

With some code below:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetAll()
    {

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        var sites = db.Site;

        if (sites == null || sites.Count() == 0)
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                Content = new StringContent("Could not find any site")
            };
            return response;

        }
        response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new JsonContent(sites)
        };

        return response;
    }
```

and JsonContent class to transform object to JSON as defined:

```
 public JsonContent(object value)
    {
        Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var JsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(_Stream));
        JsonTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        var Serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        Serializer.Serialize(JsonTextWriter, value);
        JsonTextWriter.Flush();
        _Stream.Position = 0;

    }
```

It work fine at localhost, but when i deloy it to server and call api, it return (Response Content):

```
{"Version":{"_Major":1,"_Minor":1,"_Build":-1,"_Revision":-1},"Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value"application/json"]}]},"StatusCode":200,"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Headers":[],"RequestMessage":null,"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

What wrong, I hope a help, thanks everyone.

Comment: Most likely `_Stream` is not getting set correctly or the way you think it is. How do you derive its value and what is different between local and server that would cause it?

Comment: I don't think the local and server are diffrent, as you can see, the status code is 200 it mean the query of database had success (the data just some records in table on database). could you suggest me the correct way to do this (return record set from db with http request on JSON format)

Comment: 200 means `sites` is not null and `Count()` is not zero. It doesn't mean it contains what you expect.

Comment: I am reseaching... The JSON object which i expected. Anyway thank for you discussed. Still stuck at this point